# how to get the subscription status with stripe.subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to get a customer's subscription status. I already have their customer id. I am trying to determine from their status if they have paid or have cancelled, unpaid, ended, etc. I am in php.
this is how i get their customer id

```
 $customersResponse = $stripe->customers->all(['email' => $_SESSION['userid']]);     
 $custid1 = $customersResponse->data[0]->id;
```

Now I want to get their status so I use

```
$subscriptionsResponse = $stripe->subscriptions->all(['customer' => $custid1]
$status=$subscriptionsResponse->data[0] -> status;   but status is always null
```

In my testing I am using a customer who has currently cancelled. I am finding this data[0] to be terribly hard to debug. How can I get the $status set correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe's [API reference doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-status) shows how to get subscription list and filter by `status`.

Stripe won't return 'canceled' subscriptions unless you specify `'status' => 'canceled'` or `'status' => 'all'` in the request. If `status` is omitted from the request, the response will only include non-canceled subscriptions.

You also need to pass a value for the customer parameter if you want to list a specific customer's subscription(s) only.

In short, you need to pass status and customer query parameters in your request to receive all subscriptions of specific customer.